# Python PPTX adjust XML values in existing multi-plot chart

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-pptx

I’m trying to adjust an existing multi-plot graph (bar and line chart) in an existing pptx with the python-pptx library (version: 0.6.19).

I‘ve already tried to create it with the pptx library but the api for creating those multi-plot graphs is not existing, yet. The `Chart.replace_data()` function is also not working for multi-plot graphs, therefore I‘m trying to adjust it via XML. The graph is always exactly the same, just with different values.

Here‘s my current code:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('Presentation1.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[0]
chart = slide.shapes[1].chart
print(chart.plots[1].series[0].values)
```

I can see the values of the chart via the print function but adjusting it via the values function returns an TypeError not supporting item assignment.

At the moment I cannot access the XML value. I tried the following:

```
chart.plots[1].series[0]._element.xpath(r"c:val")
```

But it‘s not returning the values. I get the message TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NonType object. What am I missing and how can I adjust the values? Sorry if it‘s obvious for you but I‘m quite new to pptx and XML.

Here‘s the relevant snippet from the XML file. The reference to Excel is not important for me:

```
<c:val>
            <c:numRef>
              <c:f>ChartDeveloper!$C$68:$H$68</c:f>
              <c:numCache>
                <c:formatCode>0.0%</c:formatCode>
                <c:ptCount val="6"/>
                <c:pt idx="0">
                  <c:v>0.23</c:v>
                </c:pt>
                <c:pt idx="1">
                  <c:v>0.22</c:v>
                </c:pt>
                <c:pt idx="2">
                  <c:v>0.22</c:v>
                </c:pt>
                <c:pt idx="3">
                  <c:v>0.2</c:v>
                </c:pt>
                <c:pt idx="4">
                  <c:v>0.18</c:v>
                </c:pt>
                <c:pt idx="5">
                  <c:v>0.16</c:v>
                </c:pt>
              </c:numCache>
            </c:numRef>
          </c:val>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out myself. Here's the code for anyone who might need it. It's also a good workaround to use a template with a dummy multi-plot to create multi-plots with python pptx library (if the dimensions stay the same):

```
prs = Presentation('Presentation1.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[0]

for el in slide.shapes[1].chart.plots[0].series[0]._element.xpath("c:val/c:numRef/c:numCache/c:pt/c:v"):
    print(el.text)
    el.text = "0.3"

prs.save('xmlDummy.pptx')
```